# Properties are undefined, when getting objects via Angular's HttpClient

Tags: angular, typescript, properties

I have a service class, that uses Angular's `HttpClient` to get data from a web service.
The web service returns a JSON object like this:

```
{
  "id": "some kind of user id",
  "name": "The user's name",
  "permissions": [ 
    "String array with different permission names"
  ]
}
```

I want the `HttpClient`'s `get<>` method to get me these objects typed as my own `DomainUser` class object.

This is the `DomainUser` class:

```
export class DomainUser {
  public id: string;
  public name: string;
  public permissions: string[];

  public get isAdmin(): boolean {
    return this.permissions.includes('admin permission's name');
  }
}
```

When I want to get the value of the `DomainUser`'s `isAdmin` property, I get the message, that `isAdmin` is undefined.
How can I get the user data correctly typed as `DomainUser`?

The `get` call is

```
this.http.get<DomainUser>(this.apiUrl + '/Users/Self').subscribe(
  next => {
    console.info('User: "%s" (Admin: %s)', next.name, next.isAdmin ? 'yes' : 'no');

    // ...
  },
  error => {
    // error handling
  }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are parsing the text to a new object, not to a new DomainUser. You can't parse a method so the method does not exist. You could do something like this:

```
this.http.get<DomainUser>(this.apiUrl + '/Users/Self')
  .map(next => Object.assign(new DomainUser(), next))
  .subscribe(next => {
      console.info('User: "%s" (Admin: %s)', next.name, next.isAdmin ? 'yes' : 'no');

    // ...
  },
  error => {
    // error handling
  }
);
```

Comment: Hi Robin, thanks for your answer. Now I get the following message: `TypeError: _this.http.get(...).map is not a function`

Comment: I also added `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` and get the same message.

Comment: `import 'rxjs/operators/add/map';`

Comment: After modifying the path (`import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';`) it works. Thank you! :)